# closing a page and going back to the previous one without losing data with playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I'm trying to collect data from a page when I click on the job_link and return to the previous page without losing the data I stored here.

I don't know which code is suitable in order to go back to the previous page and add the newly collected data to the list.

Here is the code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def extract_li_content(url):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.firefox.launch()
        context = browser.new_context(user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
        page = context.new_page()

        page.goto(url)
        ul_element = page.query_selector('ul.jobsearch-ResultsList.css-0')

        # Check if the ul element is found
        if ul_element:
            li_elements = ul_element.query_selector_all('li')
            data = []
            for li_element in li_elements:
                h2_title = li_element.query_selector('h2.jobTitle')
                if h2_title:
                    title = h2_title.inner_text()
                # Get the link to the job page
                job_link = li_element.query_selector('a#job_3b15d5e241d64aff')
                if job_link:
                    print('aaaa')
                    job_link_url='https://ma.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=3b15d5e241d64aff&tk=1h5rp9hq0ieno801&from=hp'
                    # job_link_url = job_link.get_attribute('href')
                    # print(job_link_url)
                    # print('here')
                    page.goto(job_link_url)  # Go to the job detail page directly

                    # Wait for the page to load completely
                    page.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")

                    # Get the content of the div named "hhh"
                    description = page.query_selector('div#jobDescriptionText')
                    if description:
                        job_desc = description.inner_text()
                        # print('hhh')
                        # print(job_desc)
                    data.append({'title': title, 'content': job_desc})
                    # Close the current page and go back to the previous page
                   


            return data
        else:
            print("UL element not found!")

        browser.close()

def main():
    url = 'https://ma.indeed.com/jobs?q=data&l=Casablanca&start=10&pp=gQAPAAABiWikb0sAAAACCo6AaQAkAQEBBwPX2BuBNUaplUUDw07lSjGmHFLq75AidI5KyNU_THePAAA&vjk=8632faf4009ca26e'
    li_content_data = extract_li_content(url)
    c=0
    for item in li_content_data:
        c+=1
        print(item)
        if (c==1):break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```